# Rails find_by in a lower hierarchy level

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, find-by-sql

I have the following models:

```
Company has_many Employees has_many Projects

Projects have a deadline:dateTime
```

Now I want, with a statement that generates a single SQL, to get the next deadline from any project of a given company.

i.e.

```
def get_next_deadline
   * * * select deadline from projects where employee_id in (employees.each |i| )) * * *
end
```

What I don't want is to iterate over all the companies Employees and check for the next deadline, accessing the DB once for each Employee.

Is there a more elegant find command than

```
find_by_sql?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add

```
has_many :projects, :through => :employees
```

to your company model, then you can do

```
some_company.projects.order('deadline').first
```

to find the project with the first deadline for that company

Comment: Nice, much more elegant! But why does it need to do an inner join between employees and projects. Wouldn't it be smarter to generate a 'WHERE...IN' query like I outlined in my question?

Comment: subqueries are generally slower than inner joins, as would be a first query to get a list of ids followed by a second query with an IN clause (especially if the list of employees was long). But if in doubt, benchmark!